# How do I use the BigCommerce API to update a customer's customer_group_id using core PHP?

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I'm trying to write a PHP script for my BigCommerce site that runs nightly and places customers into specific Customer Groups based on certain criteria. I can do everything else I need *other* than actually update the the customer_group_id. BigCommerce [documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/rest#customers) only shows GET methods available for customers. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer group ID on a customer can be updated. This has been around for maybe a year or more now.  You can PUT to the customer resource and the *customer_group_id* is what you would want to change.


Documented here: 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/customer


If you are using the PHP API Library then you could update a customer group ID on a customer with this kind of code:

```
$request_body = array("customer_group_id" => 10);
Bigcommerce:updateCustomer(50, $request_body);
```

The above would update the customer with ID 50 to have a new customer group ID of 10.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I currently work at Bigcommerce. Unfortunately at this time, our API doesn't support the ability to update customer group ids. However, you are encouraged to add this as a feature request to our Ideas site. http://ideas.bigcommerce.com/.

For your convenience, I have also included a link to our Dev portal, which includes the full API documentation as well as how-tos/tools and a new @Mashery powered API playground. http://developer.bigcommerce.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'll add the feature request. :)

Comment: is the feature have been added. Its more than two years ?

Comment: @Moax6629 yes, this is doable now

Comment: @JZ yea jz i know, i've already achieved that, thanks for replying though.