# How can I access extra customer registration form field values via the Bigcommerce API?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

In the bigcommerce control panel, you are given the option to 
[add extra fields to the customer registration form](https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1322/How+do+I+add+fields+in+the+registration+form+in+the+account+creation+of+my+store%3F).

This is shown in the control panel when Editing a customer record. They
show up, in the rendered html as this kind of thing:

```
<div class="field formRow ">
    <label for="FormField_24"><span class="FormFieldLabel">FIELD NAME</span>
            ...
    </label>
    <div class="field-group value">
        <input type="hidden" value="24" class="FormFieldId">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" class="FormFieldFormId">
        ...            
        <input type="text" value="FIELD VALUE" class="field-xlarge FormField" 
          name="FormField[1][24]" id="FormField_24" ...>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, walking the records with the [Customer API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/customers) doesn't show any of these extra fields.

Is there is anything in the [Bigcommerce API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/) that will let me access these custom *customer* form fields?

**Update:**

There are some older questions about this, that I didn't spot in searching ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17017893/75188), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14420502/75188)).

Given that those questions are from January & July last year, and still have no solution, it looks like this is simply a gap in the API.  Damn.

Comment: I do not think that any of the custom fields are available at this time in the Bigcommerce API.

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be the case. Was hoping I was missing something.

Comment: They are available in V3